# Could not build docker image with airflow2.0.0 using breeze

Tags: airflow

I get below error when tried to run the following breeze build command to build airflow docker. I clone the git airflow `master` branch to build this image.

Build Command:

```
./breeze build-image --production-image --python 3.7 --install-airflow-version 2.0.0 --additional-extras=jdbc --additional-python-deps="pandas" --additional-runtime-apt-deps="default-jre-headless"
```

Error:

```
    Step 83/94 : COPY scripts/docker/install*.sh /scripts/docker/
 ---> 8363694670bb
Step 84/94 : RUN if [[ ${INSTALL_FROM_PYPI} == "true" ]]; then         bash /scripts/docker/install_airflow.sh;     fi;     if [[ ${INSTALL_FROM_DOCKER_CONTEXT_FILES} == "true" ]]; then         bash /scripts/docker/install_from_docker_context_files.sh;     fi;     if [[ -n "${ADDITIONAL_PYTHON_DEPS}" ]]; then         bash /scripts/docker/install_additional_dependencies.sh;     fi;     find /root/.local/ -name '*.pyc' -print0 | xargs -0 rm -r || true ;     find /root/.local/ -type d -name '__pycache__' -print0 | xargs -0 rm -r || true
 ---> Running in 01f3dd4b7f57
+ [[ true == \t\r\u\e ]]
+ bash /scripts/docker/install_airflow.sh

Installing all packages with constraints and upgrade if needed

ERROR: Invalid requirement: 'apache-airflow[async,amazon,celery,cncf.kubernetes,docker,dask,elasticsearch,ftp,grpc,hashicorp,http,ldap,google,microsoft.azure,mysql,postgres,redis,sendgrid,sftp,slack,ssh,statsd,virtualenv,jdbc]2.0.0'
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.4; however, version 21.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
The command '/bin/bash -o pipefail -e -u -x -c if [[ ${INSTALL_FROM_PYPI} == "true" ]]; then         bash /scripts/docker/install_airflow.sh;     fi;     if [[ ${INSTALL_FROM_DOCKER_CONTEXT_FILES} == "true" ]]; then         bash /scripts/docker/install_from_docker_context_files.sh;     fi;     if [[ -n "${ADDITIONAL_PYTHON_DEPS}" ]]; then         bash /scripts/docker/install_additional_dependencies.sh;     fi;     find /root/.local/ -name '*.pyc' -print0 | xargs -0 rm -r || true ;     find /root/.local/ -type d -name '__pycache__' -print0 | xargs -0 rm -r || true' returned a non-zero code: 1

ERROR: The previous step completed with error. Please take a look at output above
```

Edit (1):

I tried the same thing on an aws ec2 instance and get the same error. Something looks like is broken on the airflow side. Below is the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: It should be --install-airflow-version="2.0.0"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
--install-airflow-version 2.0.0
```

with

```
--install-airflow-version="2.0.0"
```

So the command is:

```
./breeze build-image --production-image --python 3.7 --install-airflow-version "2.0.0" --additional-extras=jdbc --additional-python-deps="pandas" --additional-runtime-apt-deps="default-jre-headless"
```

Comment: I tried the above command with double quotes but I still get the same error. I have tried following cmd `./breeze build-image --production-image --python 3.7 --install-airflow-version="2.0.0"` and `./breeze build-image --production-image --python 3.7 --install-airflow-version "2.0.0"` but still get the same error.

Comment: this works fine for me. Try to pull the latest changes from master maybe there were changes to breeze that you didn't pull.

Comment: okay. Let me try to clone the repo in a new folder directly in my windows machine. i dont know if this matters but the above error occurred when I ran the docker build on on `WSL (Windows subsystem for Linux)`.

Comment: I tried the same command on an ec2 (AWS) instance and I get the same error.

Comment: removed everything and did clean build again and it finally worked. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
./breeze build-image --production-image --python 3.7 --install-airflow-version "==2.0.0" --additional-extras=jdbc --additional-python-deps="pandas" --additional-runtime-apt-deps="default-jre-headless"
```

had to add the "==".